# Perform adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() outside a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have one fragment that is a list of database values. I am using a ListView to display the values to the screen.

I have another fragment that contains the buttons to add entries to the database. So my problem is, is that when I add an entry to the database by hitting a button on the first fragment, I need the second fragment (or second page in the app) to update the list of database values that are shown on the screen.

Here is the database list fragment:

```
public class FragManage extends Fragment {

private PunchesDataSource datasource;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    datasource = new PunchesDataSource(getActivity());
    datasource.open();

    List<Punch> values = datasource.getAllPunches();

    // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the elements in a ListView
    ArrayAdapter<Punch> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Punch>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage, container, false);

    ListView list = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return myFragmentView;
    }
}
```

So I just want to perform adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in my other fragment that contains the buttons (something like this):

```
    // Punch OUT button.
    Button out_button = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.out_button);
    out_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            datasource.createPunch("out-" + getTime());

            FragManage.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to communicate from FragA -> MainActivity -> FragB **directly to a method (within FragB) that cannot be static** , this solution should work for you.

How it works here: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html

Code I added in MainActivity.java:

```
String FragManage;

public void setTabFragManage(String t){
    FragManage = t;
}

public String getTabFragManage(){
 return FragManage;
}
```

Code I added in FragPunch.java

```
public void onClick(View v) {

...

String TabOfFragManage = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getTabFragManage();

FragManage fm = (FragManage)getActivity()
    .getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentByTag(TabOfFragManage);

fm.update(); //This is what is NOT possible before, but now is.
}
```

Code I added in FragManage.java

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    String myTag = getTag();

        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setTabFragManage(myTag);
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use a listener with the main activity that updates the fragments

in the frag with buttons add these

```
private void onDBChanged(){
    OnDBListener.DBChanged(true);
}

public void setOnDBListener(OnDBListener listener){
    this.OnDBListener = listener;
}

public interface OnDBListener{
    public void DBChanged(boolean DB_Bool);
}
```

then in the DB frag

```
public void update(){
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then attach the listener in the Main activity that creates the frags

```
ButtonsFragment.setOnDBListener(new OnDBListener() {
    @Override
    public void DBChanged(boolean DB_Bool) {

        DatabaseViewFrag.update();
    }
});
```

when you update the database in the buttons fragment call

```
onDBChanged()
```

to tell everything it has updated

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution, but I am running into some problems. Is onDBChanged() supposed to be DBChanged()? Also, what is fsChanged(true) stand for / supposed to do?

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: sorry mate i had a typo :P i have fixed the code and added the rest i forgot.

Comment: Alright I have one more problem, how can I access `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in the update() method? I tried doing this: `((BaseAdapter) ((ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list)).getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()` but it says the method update() must not be static. The method update() is static because of `FragManage.update()`.

Comment: Hey man thanks for all the help but I couldn't get the handler to fix that problem. Luckily I found another solution using a unique fragment method. See my solution if you want.